# Unable to select drop down button for python selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

How would I select this button

[image]

and click on it?
I have tried several methods and none of them have clicked it.

Comment: How did you try? Share your current code and describe problem/share exception log

Comment: Share your trial code so far,

Comment: dropDown = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, \'btn btn-select nowrap-line\')][contains(@tabindex, \'1\')]').click()   This is one I tried recently and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

try with css selector and javaScript executor for select multi-class element and click it

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('button.btn-select.nowrap-line')[0].click()")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: This did not work when I entered it, do you have any other methods? Or could you explain this one a bit more

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the class_name selector?

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-select nowrap-line")
```

I know you said you've tried several methods, maybe list the different ways and I can probably try to see why it's failing

Comment: This won't work as compound class names are not allowed

Comment: This does not work, I had tried this as my first atempt